# Is there any benefit of using Http 2 for a Web API consumed by HttpClient?

Tags: .net, http2

We have some web APIs, although saying web APIs, they are all consumed by other team's c# code, so they will create HttpClient and send GET/POST requests.

As these web APIs are not consumed by frontend and my understanding is that Http2 mainly benefits front end (e.g. UI side). Is there any benefit to make our API sites only supporting Http2?

The support of Http2 is quite messy in .net world, for example, this code will not work well in .net framework 4.8, but will be happy in .net 5/6 or .net core.

```
yourHttpRequestMessage.Version = new Version(2, 0);
```

So this makes me think that if our site will be 100% consumed by other team's c# code via HttpClient, do we really need to support Http2?

Microsoft doc explained Http2 support [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Yes, but that's enabled automatically in ASP.NET Core projects, so there's no mess at all. You have to do extra work to disable it. What is the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: `Http2 mainly benefits front end` that's wrong. For example, gRPC is primarily a service-to-service protocol which *requires* HTTP/2.

Comment: Setting the version isn't hard either. You can set it in the `HttpClient.DefaultRequestVersion` property. That's no more messy than setting default headers. If you use HttpClientFactory you can set that in the factory configuration. This is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#http2-support)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, that document is for .net core 3, for .net framework (e.g. .net 4.8) it doesn't work like that. This exactly shows how messy it is

Comment: Server push and streaming are important benefits, especially when used with gRPC. Right now, when you start a long-running operation on another service you need to either wait for it to finish, or somehow set up a mechanism to check the operation's status. There's no way to get intermediate results either.  Request header compression is important in API scenarios too, because headers can be even larger than the body for small requests.

Comment: `is for .net core 3, for .net framework` not quite. HttpClientFactory and HttpClient are available as .NET Standard 2.0 packages for the old .NET Framework. Besides, you didn't specify that you want a solution for .NET Old.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, actually if you have a project in .net 4.8 and consumes a web api will only supports Http2 via HttpClient. Using DefaultRequestVersion  or Version will not work. You will need to use a custom WinHttpHandler.

Request header compression maybe interesting, do you have any doc on how to enable that in HttpClient or is it by default?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem? Are the *services* written in .NET Core or .NET Framework? HTTP/2 is on by default in .NET Core, and automatic negotiation ensures even older clients will keep working by falling back to HTTP/1.1. Your clients won't remain on .NET Old forever either. .NET Old is done - as in not getting any upgrades or new features, only fixes. Even 4.8 is 3 years old now.

Comment: Services are written in .net 6. But our consumers are on .net 6, .net 4.8 and some linux docker. We wanted to enforce Http 2 on our services, but that breaks lots of existing .net 4.8 consumers.

Comment: Is the problem that HttpClient protocol negotiation fails in .NET Framework 4.8? Which HttpClient version are you using? On which OS? HTTP/2 should work with .NET Framework on Windows 10, which is the oldest Windows version still in mainstream support. WinHttpHandler was needed before 4.6.x and Windows 10

Comment: Why not let the 4.8 clients can fall back to HTTP/1.1 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241924/discussion-between-daxu-and-panagiotis-kanavos).